# Using more than one WHERE condition in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to apply a multiple WHERE conditions to my query just like this:

```
$hotel="Hotel Name";
$data1=explode('/',$data1);
$newdata1=mktime(0, 0, 0, $data1[0], $data1[1], $data1[2]);
$newdata1=date("Y-m-d", $newdata1);

$data2=explode('/',$data2);
$newdata2=mktime(0, 0, 0, $data2[0], $data2[1], $data2[2]);
$newdata2=date("Y-m-d", $newdata2);

$filtro=mysql_query("SELECT * 
                    FROM hotels_rates_flat
                    WHERE htl_name = $hotel AND  
                          given_date>=$newdata1 AND 
                          given_date<=$newdata2 
                    ORDER BY htl_name, city_zone, given_date") 
             or die(mysql_error());
```

It is returning the following error:

***You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'do Hotel AND given_date>=2012-09-01 AND given_date<=2012-09-05 ORDER BY htl_nam' at line 1.***

This is really bothering me because I can't see any clear mistake.

I would appreciate any help.

Thank you

Comment: Please tell me `$hotel` is not raw user input that's being passed straight into an SQL query! That would be [BAD](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Comment: Single quote all your non-integer values you're using in your query, like @njk suggested below.

Comment: $hotel comes from a select input, not from a text input type. "Hotel Name" is just a sample. I did not use the real hote name in this matter.

Comment: I'll just point out that select input is no more secure than a text box, only a tiny bit more difficult.

Answer (score 2):

Use PDO to avoid SQL injections and error reporting:

```
<?php
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=UTF-8', 'username', 'password', array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
    $hotel="Hotel Name";                                                                                    
    $data1=explode('/',$data1);
    $newdata1=mktime(0, 0, 0, $data1[0], $data1[1], $data1[2]);
    $newdata1=date("Y-m-d", $newdata1);

    $data2=explode('/',$data2);
    $newdata2=mktime(0, 0, 0, $data2[0], $data2[1], $data2[2]);
    $newdata2=date("Y-m-d", $newdata2);

    try {
        $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `hotels_rates_flat` WHERE `htl_name` = :hotel AND (`given_date` BETWEEN :date1 AND :date2) ORDER BY `htl_name`, `city_zone`, `given_date`");
        $stmt->execute(array(':hotel' => $hotel,':date1' => $newdata1,':date2' => $newdata2));
        $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } catch(PDOException $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
    }
    // use $results
?>
```

Comment: Guys, I would like to explain a little better what I am trying to do:

Answer (score 1):

The source of your problem is quoting.  You should use a prepared statement with placeholders, and let the mysql driver figure out how to insert the values in a syntactically valid way.

You can use `mysqli_` functions similarly to `mysql_` ones, and just add a couple extra calls to handle the parameters.  You do need an explicit database handle (I call it `$dbh` below; it's returned from `mysqli_connect()`) instead of relying on an implicit one like the mysql_ functions let you do.

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbh, 'SELECT * FROM hotels_rates_flat' 
                           . ' WHERE htl_name = ?'
                           .   ' AND given_date BETWEEN ? AND ?'
                           . ' ORDER BY htl_name, city_zone, given_date');

# the 'sss' means treat all three parameters as (s)trings
mysqli_bind_param($stmt, 'sss', $hotel, $newdata1, $newdata2) or die(mysqli_error($dbh));

$filtro = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) or die(mysqli_error($dbh));
```

Or you could use PDO, as in Mihai's answer, which is a bit different.

Answer (score -2):

You need to encase `$hotel`, `$newdata1` and `$newdata2` with single quotes.

`SELECT * FROM hotels_rates_flat WHERE htl_name = '$hotel' AND  ...`

You can also use the `BETWEEN` operator instead of writing out less than & greater than:

`AND given_date BETWEEN '$newdata1' AND '$newdata2'`

You should also [stop using](http://www.deprecatedphp.com/mysql) `mysql_` functions.